# Saying 'for example' and 'e.g.'

Tags: translation, word-choice

I think that all three of these are acceptable:

- zum Beispiel (z.B)
- beispielsweise
- Bsp.

If so, are there any differences between them? Is one more formal, archaic, colloquial, etc. than the other two?

Also are there any other ways to say 'For example' or 'e.g.'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essentially, *beispielsweise* and *zum Beispiel* are interchangeable. Some manuals of style recommend against starting or ending a sentence with *zum Beispiel*, preferring *beispielsweise* in these positions; but this is not universally accepted.

Depending on context, *etwa* and *wie* (or *wie etwa*) can be used to give an example, too:

> Manche Markennamen entwickeln sich zum allgemeinen Begriff, etwa *Fö(h)n* für Haartrockner.

On the other hand, *Bsp.* by itself is just an abbreviated form of *Beispiel*. In general, it is not a replacement for *beispielsweise* or *zum Beispiel*, though it can sometimes be used to introduce an example as well, like so:

> Viele Nutzpflanzen wurden aus anderen Weltgegenden importiert. Beispiel: Die Kartoffel stammt ursprünglich aus Amerika.

This is an elliptical construction, short for *ich nenne ein Beispiel* or similar. It is rather colloquial style.

Comment: Ich finde "Bsp." umständlich und würde es in Sätzen immer ausschreiben. Als Beschriftung einer Abbildung wäre es ok. Ich denke, "z.B." ist verbreiteter und man stolpert im Lesefluss nicht so leicht darüber.

Answer (score 1):

Da Du explizit nach Sprechen fragst muss Bsp. abgelehnt werden. Allerdings wird in der Umgangssprache durchaus z.B. (Zett Be) verwendet.

Neben Chirlus *etwa* und *wie* kann man noch das *Exempel* ins Feld führen, welches häufiger statuiert wird, als aufgezählt - letzteres ist eher historischer Sprachgebrauch aber vom Kinderbuch Max & Moritz mit Lehrer Hempel wohl noch ein paar Jahrzehnte im Umlauf.